# Remove rows with INVALID status/Keep with VALID status

Tags: r

I want to remove rows from df with status invalid

```
df_new<-subset(df, select = df$STATUS == "VALID")
```

It says that I lack a column. Is it a way to do that?

Comment: You could do `df_new <- subset(df, STATUS != "INVALID")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only rows matching the condition in this way:

```
df_new<-df[df$STATUS == "VALID",]
```

Condition `df$STATUS == "VALID"` will provide a list of T/F used to select only correct rows.